# Alamofire post nextval

Tags: swift, postgresql, alamofire

How I can Post nexval use Alamofire in PostgreSQL?
I have REST API with next structure:

```
    ["ID": int,
     "Date": Datetime,
     "Boolean": Boolean,
     "String": String]
```

ID is sequence. How I can POST it? In PostgreSQL I can insert in Table with next request:

```
insert into "Table" values (nextval('"Table_ID_seq"'::regclass),'2016-02-24 12:33:37 + 0000','1','My string')
```

I have problem with POST it: `nextval('"Table_ID_seq"'::regclass)`
If instead of `nextval('"Table_ID_seq"'::regclass)` I write some Int value, all work correct.

My parameters:

```
            let now = NSDate();
            let parameters = [
            "ID":  "nextval(\'\"Table_ID_seq\"\' ::regclass)",
            "Boolean": "TRUE",
            "Datetime": "\(now)",
            "String": "My string"
        ];

            Alamofire.request(.POST, URL, parameters: parameters as? [String : AnyObject], encoding: .JSON)
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I don't have error. Data is not inserted into the table. If I write "nextval(\'\"Table_ID_seq\"\' ::regclass)" REST API look like {ID = "nextval('\"Table_ID_seq\"' ::regclass)"; ...}

Comment: if it's possible change the `ID` datatype to serial and use for inserting the fields `insert into Table ( fields, ...) values (...)` and leave the `ID` field out.

Comment: ID has serial type. If I insert into Table ( fields, ...) values (...) without ID I have an error

Comment: That depends on how the REST API is implemented. My best bet to leave the `ID` field out from your request to let the REST API generate an ID for you.

Comment: Does you mean trigger before insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. In properties field in PostgreSQL in default value put this: nextval('"Table_ID_seq"'::regclass)

And then create POST method without ID.